# Design pattern for taking user input and invoking method

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need implement a control solution for a computer game I am writing to take user input .

I am looking at the Command pattern, but not sure if its a good fit for this.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your command input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the Command pattern is overused for situations like this. If the command is entirely transient - you are not going to store or manipulate the object - then there is little point in the added complexity, object code overhead and boilerplate of using commands.

A more appropriate approach is a simple switch and method call. Perhaps you might want to separate out the interface you are calling from an implementation, although this can trivially be done later (if you like tests or traces, you'll probably do this sooner than later). If the keys can be changed, a simple map from input value to action value should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I thought Command pattern might be overengineering it a little.

I'm thinking of having an input handler class that takes input, looks up a corresponding key in a Map, and attempted to call the Maps value method via Reflection in another class, e.g.

KEY_A, performMoveLeftAction()
KEY_S, performMoveRightAction()
KEY_SPACE, performFireAction()
etc

The Map could be loaded from a file, and would allow for configuration.

Does this sound plausible, and does it conform to any particular pattern? It reads a little like a cut down Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your input, it might be worthwhile to look at the [Interpreter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) to read and parse the inputs, coupled with the Command pattern to actually execute the commands.

Answer (score 1):

The technique is usually called "[double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)", but the interpreter pattern describes the general pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In the command pattern, it's best to make commands immutable, which means no runtime input.  Don't over complicate the problem.  All you need to do is accept input real time and interpret it somehow (see Thomas' tip if you're set on a pattern).  If you're trying to eliminate a big switch statement, or large if-else block, the abstract factory pattern might be worthwhile.